# Is this cross-posting?

Tags: discussion

I realize cross-posting is frowned upon, and that's not my intent. The other question is concerned with specifics of creating a business application. I'm more interested with the security theory behind their idea. So my question is:

If someone on a different stackexchange site has asked a question that got me thinking about an interesting security question, would it still be cross-posting if I strip the interesting part out and ask it here?

Answer (score 3):

That would be absolutely fine.

Make sure it fits the guidelines in [ask] and [about] and ideally add a link to the other question to give some additional background.